# Arrow function is not working in react during the success callback in functional component

Tags: reactjs, arrow-functions, react-functional-component

Hi I'm new to React and I'm confused with Function and Arrow function, below is my case.

I have used functional component where some authorization has been done, post authorization call, success callback returns another method which I have used as Arrow method, which is not working but the same with function keyword is working below is my case.

```
const myApp= () => {

   ... // variable declartion

    myAuth.authorize({
      service: 'test',
      credentials: {},
      onsuccess:() => {
          callinganotherFunction();
      },
      fail() {}
    });

    // below arrow function is not working 
   Const callinganotherFunction = () => {
    ...
    }
    
    
    //below function method is working
    function callinganotherFunction () {
    ...
    }


}

export default myApp
```

I'm getting the below error in console while having the arrow function

```
Uncaught TypeError: callinganotherFunction is not a function
    at Object.onsuccess
```

Comment: is this your actual code? we would need to see more if there's a syntax issue

Comment: Try adding const/let in front of the arrow method

Comment: @Tushar Added const and updated my question. Tried with const and let but nothing works

Comment: @Taylor, yes this is my code there is no other issues since if I use function method it's working.

Comment: Try to declare `const callinganotherFunction = ...` before their use, at the beginning of the function

Comment: Yes, exactly @GenesisGuerreroMartinez. Functions are hoisted, but `const` and `let` are not.

Answer (score 0):

Declaring a function with let or const will not hoist them so you can use them before the declaration. You can use var or better declare the function before calling it.